# Java ProcessBuilder and whitespace args

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, processbuilder

I know this has been asked before, but none of the solutions worked for me. Essentially what I need to is execute a command that has spaces in it. This is what I have so far:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"java", "-Xms512m", "-Xmx1024m", "-cp", jars, natives, mc});
```

The spaces come from `"jars"` and `"natives"`, because the file paths have a space in them (`"Application Support"` because I'm on a mac)

From what I've seen this should work, but it gives me a `NoClassDefFoundError`, and if I copy and paste it into a terminal window it works fine. Also the spaces are escaped like this: `"Application\ Support"`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a `String` to parse through to the `Runtime`, which contains spaces in it. You will almost certainly need to wrap the spaced-content with quotes, either single or double...

This shows it using a single `String`, with double-quote wrapping around your variables...

```
String command = "java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -cp \"" + jars + "\" \"" + natives + "\" \"" + mc + "\"";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

You could also probably do it by wrapping your content in double-quotes in your existing code...

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"java", "-Xms512m", "-Xmx1024m", "-cp", "\""+jars+"\"", "\""+natives+"\"", "\""+mc+"\""});
```

You need single or double quotes around any white-space content so that it is interpreted as a single value.

You also mention that you're getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` message - if this is still the case, please post the full stack trace so that we can see what the error is complaining about, as it sounds like maybe something else is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-Xms512m", "-Xmx1024m", "-cp", jars, natives, mc);
Process p = pb.start();
```

You can even put it in one line:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-Xms512m", "-Xmx1024m", "-cp", jars, natives, mc).start();
```

This should work with spaces.